# Qemu Booting on a Windows image disk keeps crashing on startup

Tags: windows, qemu, bsod

I have dumped a SSD to a raw image file with dd. It is mountable and seems to be working fine. The OS installed is a Windows 7 32bits.
I tried to start a vm on qemu with this image disk as "hda" :

```
qemu-system-i386 -enable-kvm -hda my_image.001 -m 1024 -vga std &
```

I tried it with `qemu-system-x86_64` too.
When the vm starts, the windows logo appears and a BSOD occurs. I do not have time to read the error message.

When it restarts it says that due to a recent hardware change windows has failed and starts on a windows repair tool.
The windows repair tool fails to fix the problem

Since Windows seems to start booting before crashing, I am guessing this is due to some driver being missing from the disk for windows to load. Is there a way to get the actual error or missing driver?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

According to the following link, I need to retrieve the drivers for the qemu emulated hardware and put it on the disk I want to use. I will try copying the drivers from a working VM to the one I want to fix.
http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-repair-windows-7-install-after-replacing-motherboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to drivers being loaded automatically at startup. Disabling the corresponding registry keys of the OS forces Windows to reload new drivers on next boot.
It worked properly.

in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services"
Set the "Start" value to 0 for Amdide iaStorV and pciide.

Comment: Hi do you have any information about which registry keys need to be edited? I'm trying to get a windows image to boot through qemu and it just blue screens and reboots when I start it up.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding those registry keys. What is the command line you are using to boot your window image on qemu?